# Can I deploy my app through one ios developer account on ios devices and then distribute it through another account

Tags: unreal-engine4, iphone-developer-program, iosdeployment

I wanted to deploy my app on ios devices for testing purposes and I currently don't have any developer account. My friend owns one , so I wanted to ask if I could generate development signing certificates through his account for testing and then make my own account later for distribution??

Comment: Yes you can use friends developer account. There is no any problem if you use another developer account for distribution.

Comment: But you need to create different App Id